# Two thankyou actions in woocommerce when using twilio

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, twilio

In the woocommerce thankyou.php file there are two thankyou actions

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->payment_method, $order->id ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->id ); ?>
```

In my code I have added an action for one in the functions.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_complete_order_sms' );
function custom_woocommerce_complete_order_sms( $order_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        if ( !$order_id )
        return;
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        $product_list = '';
        $order_item = $order->get_items();

        foreach( $order_item as $product ) {
            $prodct_name[] = $product['name']."x".$product['qty'];

        }

        $product_list = implode( ',', $prodct_name );
        $order_amount = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_total', true );






    // Step 1: Download the Twilio-PHP library from twilio.com/docs/libraries, 
    // and move it into the folder containing this file.
    require "twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php";

    // Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
    $AccountSid = "xxxx";
    $AuthToken = "xxx";

    // Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    // Step 4: make an array of people we know, to send them a message. 
    // Feel free to change/add your own phone number and name here.

    $name = "Test";
    $number = "xxxx";
    // $number is a phone number above, and 
    // $name is the name next to it

        $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

        // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
        // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
            "+44xxxxxx", 

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $number,

            // the sms body
            "Hey $name, there is a new  Order, the order is, $product_list, the order ID is $order_id and the total amount payable is $order_amount"
        );

        // Display a confirmation message on the screen
        //echo "Sent message to $name";
    }
```

This sends a message on order, the message is sent twice a lot of the time, would this because of the two thank you actions within the woocommerce template file?

Tried to find some documentation on that file but couldn't really find much.

Not sure if safe to delete one and which one to delete, can anyone point me in the right direction

Also odd how it doesn't happen all the time, I guess another option would be writing to logs and see why instiagted it?

Answer (score 2):

This one is deceptive, because these are actually two totally different hooks. Notice that one ends with an underscore character, and then is followed by a dot concatenator  and the variable holding the payment method. This hook is dynamic and will resolve to something like `woocommerce_thankyou_stripe` or `woocommerce_thankyou_paypal`, etc.

I'm not totally sure why, but WooCommerce sometimes loads the thankyou.php template multiple times in a single checkout. The best way to counter this is probably to set a session variable to check and see if you've sent the SMS yet or not. I've updated your code to include this check:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_complete_order_sms' );
function custom_woocommerce_complete_order_sms( $order_id ) {

    // Check for the existence of a session, and start one if it's not been started yet
    // Note that session_status() is only available in PHP 5.4.0+
    if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
        session_start();
    }

    // Check for the existnece of a session variable indicating we've sent the SMS, which we set at the end
    // Abort the function if we've already sent the SMS
    if (isset($_SESSION['is_sms_sent'])) {
        return;
    }

    global $woocommerce;
    if ( !$order_id )
        return;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $product_list = '';
    $order_item = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $order_item as $product ) {
        $prodct_name[] = $product['name']."x".$product['qty'];

    }

    $product_list = implode( ',', $prodct_name );
    $order_amount = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_total', true );

    // Step 1: Download the Twilio-PHP library from twilio.com/docs/libraries,
    // and move it into the folder containing this file.
    require "twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php";

    // Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
    $AccountSid = "xxxx";
    $AuthToken = "xxx";

    // Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    // Step 4: make an array of people we know, to send them a message.
    // Feel free to change/add your own phone number and name here.

    $name = "Test";
    $number = "xxxx";
    // $number is a phone number above, and
    // $name is the name next to it

    $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

    // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number
    // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
        "+44xxxxxx",

        // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
        $number,

        // the sms body
        "Hey $name, there is a new  Order, the order is, $product_list, the order ID is $order_id and the total amount payable is $order_amount"
    );

    // Set our session variable after we've sent the SMS
    $_SESSION['is_sms_sent'] = true;

    // Display a confirmation message on the screen
    //echo "Sent message to $name";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful, I will intergrate and check , then mark as right once tests pass